# How to do RBF using the Ledger Nano / Ledger Live

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, ledger-hardware-wallet, replace-by-fee, child-pays-for-parent

Would anyone here please be able to tell me how to do RBF using the ledger nano- I can see the transaction has been stuck for about 12 hours now. The TX is 4acdaa2926d62893b15b186974bfff6cb2d13aa5c04c1121f58d9a2f607a4ee5 and it still has not been accepted.

I have been looking at accelerating it and also RBF, I have been unable to find anything for RBF in line with Ledger Live. I would really appreciate any help and if you could look at the transaction ID for me. I do not understand it unfortunately.

Many Thanks

Comment: [Blockchair.com](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/transaction/4acdaa2926d62893b15b186974bfff6cb2d13aa5c04c1121f58d9a2f607a4ee5) shows that transaction as having 32 confirmations -- so there is no longer any need to do anything.

Answer (score 2):

> **I have been unable to find anything for RBF in line with Ledger Live.**

So far as I can tell, the "Ledger Live" app does not support RBF.

You can [use Electrum with a Ledger Nano](https://www.ledger.com/supported-crypto-assets). Electrum supports RBF.

[image]